# Java compilation fails using split function

Tags: java

I have the following code but it does not work. Not sure what is wrong here:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;


class Ideone
{
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
  {
    String ext_time = "23:24:25+26";
    String short_time[] = ext_time.split("+");
    System.out.print(short_time[0]);
  }
}
```

I wanted to take string 23:24:25 out of 23:24:25+22. How would I do it?

Comment: It fails with Main.java:13: error: illegal start of expression
  String short_time[] = ext_time.split(+);

Comment: It seems that you compiled other version of code. Code that you posted is OK (from compiler point of view). I think that you tried to compile code where `+` was not surronded by `""`. Then fix regex by escaping `+`.

Comment: Style note: You legally _can_ put brackets after the name of the array you're declaring, but it isn't good practice. That declaration should instead be `String[] short_time`.

Comment: @APerson: Legally, you can do *both* (and they team up). *-shudder-*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the `+` character:

```
String short_time[] = ext_time.split("\\+");
```

Normally, the plus `+` character is a quantifier in `regex`, meaning `at least one of the previous character/group`. So to split with the character, it needs to be escaped. And since the backslash`\` is itself a special character, it needs to be escaped also. Thus, `"\\+"`.

Comment: This is right, but OP says that the code is not compiled.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-

That's because split uses a regex argument, and + is a specific operator that needs to be escaped in a regex.

Answer (score 1):

Firts is not a good name variable with brackets `short_time[]`,

but ok, I runned your code and had: Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '+' near index 0

'+' is a meta character of regEx, like bar or dot you have to escape it use `ext_time.split("\\+");`

Answer (score 1):

In split command '+' without escape will mean following :

'+' -->     Occurs one or more times, is short for {1,} X+ - Finds one or several letter X

Please escape '+' character in your regex, Hence your new code will be

`String short_time[] = ext_time.split("\\+");`

Please refer following link for more details on split regex :
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html